# Error creating dynamically a directive that has transcluded content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my application there is a point where I create dynamically a directive that has a transcluded content that I want to attach into a container (div). I used this approach for several component I have done and it works well. But now I have an issue because this directive has transcluded content. I receive an error like this:

> angular.js:14199 Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'compA', required by directive 'compB', can't be found!

Any help would be appreciated

This is the code that creates and add the component to the container

```
var newScope = $rootScope.$new(true);
newScope.elementConfig = elementConfiguration;
newScope.componentApi = {};
containerElement.append($compile(elementToHost)(newScope));
```

and this is the component I want to add to the container

```
<field
    type="{{type}}"
    model=""
    mdt="{{mdt_type}}"
    label="{{label}}"
    placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
    maxlength="{{maxlength}}"
    req="isMandatory"
    editable="editable"
    is-disabled="disabled">

<micro-help micro-help="{{'text.label' | translate }}"
                as-tooltip="true"
                position="right"
                micro-help-icon="fa-globe">
    <div>
        <micro-help-localization>
        </micro-help-localization>
    </div>
</micro-help>

</field>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker demo that reproduces problem? Not really enough shown here to resolve that error. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when HTML compiler tries to process a directive that specifies the `require` option in a directive definition, but the required directive controller is not present on the current DOM element (or its ancestor element, if `^` was specified).

To resolve this error ensure that there is no typo in the required controller name and that the required directive controller is present on the current element.

For more information, see [AngularJS Error Reference - $compile:ctreq
Missing Required Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq)